# Overwritting data and still keeping data drop down list data

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I would like to know if its possible to overwrite the rows with new data but still keep the previous data in a drop down list?
What I am trying to do is loop through a list of associates and if the condition is true, add the data on a new row, take that data and create a drop down list, then move onto the next associate. The code I have works but it is adding onto to the previous data and just making the drop downlist bigger. I also tried clearContents on column(3) after the inner loop is finished but it clears out the previous drop downlist data.

```
        For j = 2 To GetRowLength("HR")
            If shHR.Range("B" & j) = shIS.Range("F" & i) Then
                shHR.Range("C" & GetRowLength("HR", 3) + 1) = shHR.Range("A" & j)
            End If
        Next j

        With shIS.Range("O" & i).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=HR!$C:$C"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With

    Next i 


    For i = 2 To GetRowLength("Interview_Schedule")
        For j = 2 To GetRowLength("HR")
            If shHR.Range("B" & j) = shIS.Range("F" & i) Then
                shHR.Range("C" & GetRowLength("HR", 3) + 1) = shHR.Range("A" & j)
            End If
        Next j

        Dim arr()
        arr = Application.Transpose(shHR.Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value)
        With shIS.Range("O" & i).Validation
            .Delete
            ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + 1)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = shIS.Range("O" & i)
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(arr(), ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With

    Next i
```

Comment: Excel Validation list taking data from a given range will always show the updated values from the range to the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You may use dynamic array in Formula1 definition instead.
Watch this code, but I'm not sure You're looking for this:

**NOTE: This solution has a limit -> LEN(Join(arr(), ",")) <= 8190**

```
Dim bAddNewItem As Boolean
Dim arr()

' Fill out an array once somewhere at the beginning of the procedure
arr = Application.Transpose(Sheet("HR").Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value)

' If You want to add new item change to True
bAddNewItem = False

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    If bAddNewItem Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = Selection.Value
    End If
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(arr(), ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

If you want to work on larger data, using named ranges is necessary

```
    ' Add this line before updating Column C    
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add name:="myRng", RefersTo:="=" & Sheet("HR").Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Address

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=myRng"
        ' rest of code
```

Comment: Hi Barney, this was actually my first approach but the next row down just tacks onto the previous associates. I need new data

Comment: I got it. I erased the sheet after each iteration. I will post my updated code above the first example.

Comment: @SJD If I understand your comment correctly, you've changed the code in your question to include the solution? So the problem can no longer be duplicated with the code in the question and it invalidates this answer? This is not how Stack Overflow was designed to be used. If barneyo's answer solved the problem it should be marked as "the answer" by clicking the checkmark at its left. If your solution differs significantly from that suggestion, your code, *with explanation*, should be posted as a new Answer. I'm rolling back your recent edits so that the question remains valid for future users.